# How to extract parts from cell array 

Tags: matlab

I need to extract from cell array `<1x1 cell>`.

For example `> '22.11.2011 13:58:56.16'` from this `<1x1 cell>`, I want to extract the time in
seconds (`:56`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could parse the date string using [DATEVEC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html):

```
str = '22.11.2011 13:58:56.16';
[~,~,~,~,~,sec] = datevec(str, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is fixed:

```
cellArray = {'22.11.2011 13:58:56.16'};
seconds = cellArray{1}(18:19);
```

If not, you could e.g. search for the last `:` and take the two following characters:

```
lastColon = find(':'==cellArray{1}, 1, 'last');
seconds = cellArray{1}(lastColon+1:lastColon+2);
```